# Kubectl auth can-i returns different results different results than ClusterRole has

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

[image]

As can be seen in the 3 commands above, the `k auth can-i` utility is stating that the service account named strimzi-cluster-operator lacks permissions that are clearly granted to it in the cluster role. For example, listing nodes.

Any ideas?

Comment: NOTE!!!:
k auth can-i defaults to NO even if you give it a user or service account that DOESN'T EXIST! This is important. It will not tell you that the User/SA doesn't exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Access is given to ServiceAccount so can also try something like :

```
kubectl auth can-i get secrets --as=system:serviceaccount:kafka:ServiceAccount
```

Comment: Thank you! Trying this like so yields the same "no" however:

`kubectl auth can-i get secrets --as=system:serviceaccount:strimzi-cluster-operator:ServiceAccount`

Comment: Interestingly, running this command with ServiceAccounts that don't even exist also says "no"...yet I've confirmed that the `strimzi-cluster-operator` SA definitely exists in the kafka namespace

Comment: seems you tried otherwise: kubectl auth can-i get secrets --as=system:serviceaccount:kafka:strimzi-cluster-operator

Comment: You're right! I got the fully qualified name for the resources wrong. This worked:

`k auth can-i get nodes --as=system:serviceaccount:kafka:strimzi-cluster-operator`

Answer (score 0):

Check like this

```
kubectl auth can-i  list nodes --as strimzi-cluster-operator
```

It should return 'yes'

Comment: Without fully qualifying it as a ServiceAccount like this: `--as=system:serviceaccount:kafka:strimzi-cluster-operator `, it assumes you're asking for a user. Seeing that the USER strimzi-cluster-operator doesn't exist at all, it returns "no". That was my issue